# No reverse debugging for C++ Eclipse project

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, debugging

I installed Eclipse CDT and MinGW on Windows 8.1 and can launch an "Hello World" project but have no reverse debugging controls.
I saw on the net that I had to activate them in the "Customize Perspective" dialog.

When I try to activate the different commands (like "reverse resume, reverse step into") in the "Tool Bar Visibility" tab  I get the error message

> the command  cannot be made visible in this dialog

How can I enable the reverse debugging controls in Eclipse (CDT)?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem (and error message) under Linux.

I followed [this Eclipse FAQ entry](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_do_Reverse_Debugging.3F) which seems to be a bit dated. What I actually ended up doing was:

- menu Window -> Perspective -> Customize Perspective... 
  [image: Menu path to Customize Perspective menu]
- tab "Action Set Availability": check "Reverse Debugging"
  [image]

After enabling reverse debugging there, I still cannot change the visibility in the "Tool Bar Visibility" tab of the Customize Perspective Dialog but I get another icon in the tool bar that says "Reverse toggle".

[image: Image of the reverse toggle button with disabled reverse debugging]

upon turning on reverse debugging via that button I have the full set of reverse debugging controls in the tool bar.

[image: Reverse debugging enabled by pressing the "Reverse toggle" button]